# Cannot set property 'id' of undefined. Не грузится внешний скрипт в компонент. Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular

Есть модуль от стороннего разработчика, подключается скриптом. Если подключать его в index, то все грузится. Но если подключать в компоненте, то вылезает ошибка Cannot set property 'id' of undefined.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ui.sletat.ru/module-5.0/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.srvice.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScriptService {
  private loadResource(src: string): Observable<void> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.async = true
      script.src = src
      script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        observer.next()
        observer.complete()
      })

      document.head.appendChild(script)
  })
}

  private patchDocumentWrite(id: string): void {
    document.write = (input: string): void => {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += input
    }
  } 

  public loadExternalResources(): Observable<void> {
    return of(null).pipe(
      tap(() => this.patchDocumentWrite('home')),
      switchMap(() => this.loadResource('src/app/scripts/search5.js'))
   )
  }
```

home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private scriptService: ScriptService) { }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.scriptService.loadExternalResources().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('скрипт загружен');
    })
  }
}
```

home.component.html

```
<div class = "tour-select">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tour-tabs" id="nav-tab-tour" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item menu-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link tour-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Туры</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item menu-item">
        <a class="nav-link tour-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Экскурсионные туры</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
      <span class="sletat-copyright">Идет загрузка модуля <a href="https://sletat.ru/" title="поиск туров" target="_blank">поиска туров</a> &hellip;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Скрипты модуля:
app.js

```
!function() {
"use strict";
function a() {
    return document.querySelectorAll("#" + j)[0] || null
}
function b() {
    return !!a()
}
function c() {
    var b = a();
    return null !== b && "1" === b.getAttribute("data-is-loaded")
}
function d() {
    var a, b, c = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], d = 32, e = [];
    for (b = 0; b < d; b++)
        a = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length),
        e.push(c[a]);
    return e.join("")
}
function e(a, b) {
    var c = window.document.createElement("script");
    return c.async = !0,
    c.src = a,
    c.charset = "utf-8",
    c.type = "text/javascript",
    b && "string" == typeof b && (c.id = b),
    c
}
function f(a) {
    return !a.src && -1 !== (a.textContent || a.text).indexOf("sletat.createModule5")
}
function g(a) {
    return a.src && (-1 !== a.src.indexOf("module-5.0/app.js") || -1 !== a.src.indexOf("module-5.0/search/app.js"))
}
function h(a) {
    return !a.getAttribute("data-processed")
}
function i(a) {
    var b, c, d = window.document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (c = 0; c < d.length; c++)
        a(d[c]) && h(d[c]) && (b = d[c],
        b.setAttribute("data-processed", "1"));
    return b
}
var j = "sletat-module5-script";
window.sletat = window.sletat || {},
window.sletat.createModule5 = window.sletat.createModule5 || function() {
    function h(a, b) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            m[1].initialScriptID = b,
            window.sletat.initModule5.apply(null, a)
        }, 0)
    }
    function k(a) {
        function b() {
            a.setAttribute("data-is-loaded", "1"),
            h(m, n)
        }
        function c() {
            b(),
            a.removeEventListener("load", c)
        }
        function d() {
            "complete" !== a.readyState && "loaded" !== a.readyState || (b(),
            a.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", d))
        }
        a.addEventListener ? a.addEventListener("load", c, !1) : a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", d)
    }
    var l, m = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0), n = d(), o = i(f), p = i(g);
    o.id = n,
    b() && c() ? h(m, n) : b() && !c() ? (l = a(),
    k(l)) : (l = e(p.src.replace("app.js", "module.js"), j),
    k(l),
    o.parentNode.insertBefore(l, o))
}
}();
```

Исполняемый скрипт модуля слишком громоздкий, поэтому просто выкладываю код тестовой страницы. На ней модуль отлично работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ui.sletat.ru/module-5.0/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">sletat.createModule5('Search', {
  enabledCurrencies : ["RUB", "EUR", "USD"],
  useCard           : false,
  formType          : "full"
});</script>
    <span class="sletat-copyright">Идет загрузка модуля <a href="https://sletat.ru/" title="поиск туров" target="_blank">поиска туров</a> &hellip;</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А где у вас описан метод `loadExternalResources5`?

Comment: Очепятка. Исправил.

Comment: А теперь покажите, в каком месте вылезает ошибка.

Comment: app.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.window.sletat.createModule5 (app.js:1)
    at search5.js:1
window.sletat.createModule5 @ app.js:1
(anonymous) @ search5.js:1

Comment: Почему вы не используете просто import?

Comment: потому что через этот сервис методом loadExternalResources() у меня подгружаются 5 модулей, для каждого компонента свой модуль, в каких-то компонентах подгружаю сразу несколько модулей.

Comment: Извините, но это не ответ на мой вопрос) Почему вы не используете `import`?

Comment: А можно конкретнее? Что значит использовать import? Импортировать скрипт в компоненту import 'script-path/script.js'? Так не будет работать.

Comment: Да, именно так ` import 'script-path/script.js'`. Почему так не будет работать?

Comment: Потому что не будет. Выдаст ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null

Comment: Ясно, что ничего не ясно. А код этого модуля есть?

Comment: sletat.createModule5('Search', {
  enabledCurrencies : ["RUB", "EUR", "USD"],
  useCard           : false,
  formType          : "full"
});

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko он использует сторонние плагины (типа комментарии facebook), которые вставляют `iframe` через `document.write`, поэтому технически напрямую импортировать их низя :(

Comment: К сожаление, вы привели в пример не код скрипта, а код его инициализации. @overthesanity спасибо за пояснения.

Comment: Добавил скрипт module-5.0/app.js. Скрипт самого модуля просто огромный, поэтому выкладывать его сюда не стану. Вставил код тестовой страницы. Просто можете ее запустить и посмотреть основной код.